# Close Eclipse ViewPart tab when createPartControl function fails when launched from "Quick Access"?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

The default behaviour when creating a new Eclipse ViewPart is to show the new tab regardless of what happens in the createPartControl function. For example, if didn't create anything, no widgets, nothing, a blank tab will be shown. I don't like this behaviour. I want to close that tab if initialization in createPartControl fails.

Now, I have a mouse-button-context-menu handler that can do this, e.g.

```java
public class MyPartMB3Handler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event)
    throws ExecutionException {
        // Create a view and show it.
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        try {
            MyPart viewPart = (MyPart)page.showView(MyPart.ID);
            if(!viewPart.isCreated()) {
                page.hideView(viewPart);
            }
        }
        catch(PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The isCreated function is a little hack that lets me know if my ViewPart initialization fails, e.g.

```java
public class MyPart extends ViewPart {

    public static final String ID = "com.myplugin.MyPart";
    private Composite _parent = null;

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        if(!MyPlugin.createPartControl(parent) { // Some common part creation code I use.
            //PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().hideView(this);
            return;
        }
        _parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }

    public boolean isCreated() {
        return _parent != null;
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I launch this ViewPart from the Eclipse "Quick Access" field. I don't own the handler now. From an exception I forced, the handler might be org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl or  org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl or org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create.

I tried hiding the view inside the createPartControl function (see the commented line above), but Eclipse did not like that and spewed a pile of exceptions.

I thought maybe I could throw a PartInitException in createPartControl, but Eclipse tells me I'm not allowed to do that.

So, how do I get my menu handler behaviour when launching from "Quick Access"?

An underlying question might be, is there a better/proper way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: It is more usual for the view part to display a message in the view area containing an error message if there is some reason that the view cannot be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the view by running the `hideView` asynchronously after the `createPartControl` has finished - like this:

```java
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

  parent.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      getSite().getPage().hideView(MyPart.this);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Wow. Sometimes you just can't see the forest for the trees. That is such a great and simple answer. I feel a little embarrassed for not thinking of it myself. Thank you!